# LVP plastic crackling (not loud) sound

Tags: flooring

[image]We are in a process of installing (~1100ft) ESPC/LVP floors over the OSB subfloor and noticed that when you walk sometimes(!) it's making a plastic crackling sound (not loud, but still noticeable with steps) like sand under the board or in seams or seam tension). Floors were leveled within range of ~2-3mm over 10ft as recommended, clean, no dust under the board, no underlayment over OSB, plenty of space around for expansion gaps. I'm wondering if that is normal and should LVP settle over time or this is an issue?

1. Brand: Provenza Moda Living collection, ESPC
2. Connection type: Uniclick

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to [edit] your post to indicate the brand and even specific type/model of flooring, as there are a variety of ways for them to connect and that could impact an answer.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks, done

Comment: No underlayment?  Does it have "built in" underlayment?

Comment: yes, it does have attached pad

Comment: Do joints between boards (including joints at end of boards) fit tight (impossible to move) or do they flex when they touch each other?

Comment: Just wondering if the subfloor not as solid as it could be.  Any give to the subfloor?  If jumping on it, does it feel rock solid or is there a bit of bounce to it?

Comment: @crip659 that was my next idea too, since that is OSB over 2x10's I would not say it's solid as a rock, but I would not feel when I step on it that it bounces, yes when kids jump on it, I can feel it. 
Do you think cross bracing from the basement (unfinished) could help? 
I'm wondering SLC  may help to make them sturdy if that is an issue

Comment: Everything else seems to be good/done right so it seems either the joints not locked in tight or the floor has some give to it.  How thick is the OSB?

Comment: @LeeSam I would say - tight, no way to move

Comment: @crip659 well, not sure about the thickness, looks like 23/32" flooring OSB

Comment: Did your floor stop making that sound? Ours does the same and we are 1 month with no improvements.